# Is there a way I could redirect to a common php based pdf display template when a user clicks a link to a PDF file?

Tags: php, html, pdf, redirect

Is there a way I could redirect users to a pdf display template inside my website rather than going directly to the pdf file in their browser.

For example, if a user clicks on a link to http://example.com/docs/date/1.pdf

I want him to be redirected to let's say http://example.com/docview.php and this PHP needs to get details of the pdf file from the URL of the previous link and then display the right PHP file.

All help appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is little confusing.Please Make it clear and add some of your code to review.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1 - Use htaccess Rewrite rules to turn PDF accesses into PHP. This has the advantage that the user will see a link that actually says "PDF" in the URL. However, it can get a bit tricky to implement and you need to be careful that it is limited or you could easily end up with **ALL** PDFs anywhere on the site, including some that should just be static PDF files, redirecting to the script. This will do exactly what you ask - Google htaccess Rewrite and you can get plenty of examples.

2 - Change the links to reference your PHP scripts directly. The PHP script can then provide whatever frame or viewer desired or simply check for permission (if needed) and read the PDF file and output it to the browser. A .php extension on the URL doesn't mattter - the browser will display PDFs correctly based on the mimetype of the output. This is my personal preference for providing PDF output and I have done this many times.